# Tomcat and SSL, one site on https and two sites on http

Tags: tomcat, ssl

i have a server with TOMCAT and i want to configure multiple sites, 
i can configure one site on https and others sites on http?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tomcat supports virtual hosting. Download the latest release for the major version you are using (assuming you are using a current, supported version) and read the Virtual Hostinbg HOW-TO which is part of the Tomcat documentation.